# unable to open password protected pdf file with itext

Tags: java, pdf, encryption, itext

I am trying to use iText java library to open encrypted files. I know the owner password of the files. While some files are opened successfully some fail with `com.itextpdf.text.exceptions.BadPasswordException: PdfReader not opened with own
er password`

I am using the latest version of the iText using the below gradle dependency

`compile group: 'com.itextpdf', name: 'itextpdf', version: '5.0.6'`

And the code is same as in example page - http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/security-itext5/encrypting-decrypting-pdfs

I am able to open the files manually by providing same password.

What could be missing?

Comment: You are not using the latest version of iText. The latest version of iText in the 5 series is 5.5.11. The version you use, 5.0.6, was released in February 2011. 6 years ago.

Comment: Thanks @AmedeeVanGasse I updated the version. It then failed to run as bouncycastle was missing. After adding `compile group: 'org.bouncycastle', name: 'bcprov-jdk15on', version: '1.57'` (latest); It still failed with same error

Comment: Check the `pom.xml` of iText to find out the dependencies. I am not familiar with Gradle so I can't help you there.

Comment: If you cannot get it to work with iText 5.5.11, please share a sample PDF and password that illustrate the issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot share the document which has issues.The little information I can share about that is it is income tax document, and is generated by Government Dept. Not sure if this information will help